# Наша жизнь или наши жизни?

Tags: сложное-предложение, множественное-число, выбор-варианта

Оба варианта правильные?

*Они не заслуживают смерти из-за того, во что превратилась наша жизнь.*

*Они не заслуживают смерти из-за того, во что превратились наши жизни.*

Comment: "Они" живут вместе или порознь?

Answer (score 1):

Оба варианта верны, но семантические оттенки разные (авторский выбор по контексту):

(1) ***Они не заслуживают смерти из-за того, во что превратилась наша жизнь*** (жизнь нашего общества).

(2) ***Они не заслуживают смерти из-за того, во что превратились наши жизни*** (жизнь каждого из нас).

Если посмотреть в **Нацкорпусе**, то там используются оба сочетания, но с разной частотностью (наша жизнь – 1590 примеров, наши жизни – 101 пример).

**Разные смысловые оттенки** возможны в обоих вариантах, но в целом можно сказать следующее.  В первом случае жизнь чаще рассматривается как **нечто целое**, в то время как во втором это частный или обобщенный **индивидуальный** подход.

Примеры

Однако он был из другой, из моей жизни, а **наши жизни**, к сожалению, всё больше и больше расходились в разные стороны. [Анатолий Рыбаков. (1975-1977)]

Если говорить на бытовом языке, **наши жизни** состоят из сцепленных друг с другом ситуаций и положений. [Виктор Пелевин. (2014)]

**Наша жизнь** ― лишь песчинка в равнодушном океане бесконечности. [Сергей Довлатов. (1986)]

А когда нам кажется, что **наша жизнь** зашла в тупик и нам не хватает нового и яркого, каких-то путешествий, приключений и так далее ― это просто указание, что из нас открывается не особо интересный вид … [Виктор Пелевин. (2014)]

А как она должна складываться? **Наша жизнь**? Сегодня? Мне кажется, что сегодняшнее общество абсолютно аморфно. [Константин Мильчин, 2009]

Answer (score 0):

«Превратилась наша жизнь» — так можно сказать про пару, потому что про них допустимо фигурально сказать, что у них, словно одна жизнь на двоих. Но если это не пара, следует сказать: «превратились наши жизни».